# Buscar hasta n Duplicados en Diccionario

Tags: c#, linq, genericos

Se tiene el siguiente dictionary...

```
    Dictionary <int,string> dCits = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    dCits.Add(1,"London");
    dCits.Add(2, "London");
    dCits.Add(3, "Paris");
    dCits.Add(4, "Berlin");
    dCits.Add(5, "Paris");
    dCits.Add(6, "Madrid");
    dCits.Add(7, "Berlin");
    dCits.Add(8, "Madrid");
    dCits.Add(9, "Madrid");
    dCits.Add(10, "Atenas");
    dCits.Add(16, "London");
    dCits.Add(62, "Paris");
    dCits.Add(63, "Roma");
```

la idea es tomar las ciudades que solo se repiten N veces si N es 2 London se tomarán las una y hasta 2 veces, o si N es 3 tomar los tres london o 3 madrid inclusive las de 2 y 1.
si solo se requiere 1 osea N=1 seria como un Distinct... (como indico en el código abajo)  el problema es cuando son mas de 1 que no queda bien el distinct

```
foreach(var value in dCits.Values.Distinct())
{
  // aca indicar cuantas veces se necesitan dependiendo de N. 
 }
```

alguna idea, así sea con linq, un select u otro comando para resolver esto?

**UPDATE** El resultado del nuevo diccionario seria  algo asi:

si N=2

```
1,"London"
2, "London"
3, "Paris"
4, "Berlin"
5, "Paris"
6, "Madrid"
7, "Berlin"
8, "Madrid"
10, "Atenas"
63, "Roma"
```

si solo se requieren al menos 2 repetidos y seleccionando también los que hay uno. Por ejemplo roma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrupamos por los valores, y lo aplicamos a un nuevo diccionario que tenga como clave la ciudad y como valor la cuenta de valores.. y luego con un where, filtramos la lista

```
Dictionary <int,string> dCits = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dCits.Add(1,"London");
dCits.Add(2, "London");
dCits.Add(3, "Paris");
dCits.Add(4, "Belin");
dCits.Add(5, "Paris");
dCits.Add(6, "Madrid");
dCits.Add(7, "Berlin");
dCits.Add(8, "Madrid");
dCits.Add(9, "Madrid");
dCits.Add(10, "Atenas");
dCits.Add(16, "London");
dCits.Add(62, "Paris");
dCits.Add(63, "Roma");
int n = 3;
var v = dCits.GroupBy(o => o.Value)
    .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, g => g.Count())
    .Where(o => o.Value <= n);
var nuevo = dCits.Where(o => v.contains(o.value));
```

y te quedarian en nuevo las claves que vos queres

Comment: en la actualización creo explicar y colocar un ejemplo, sin embargo el group no me serviria ya que se necesitan los que repiten N veces

Comment: @ger hubieras empezado por ahi... :(

Comment: @ger igual, con este nuevo diccionario, podrias reconstruir el otro... ahora edito

Comment: me aparece error en v.Contains(o.Value) 
'IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>>' no contiene una definición para 'Contains' 
y la mejor sobrecarga del método de extensión 
'ParallelEnumerable.Contains<string>(ParallelQuery<string>, string)' 
requiere un receptor del tipo 'ParallelQuery<string>'

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar `GroupBy` para agrupara los valores  y aplicar `any` para solo los que se repiten mayor a 1.

Ejemplo:

```
var duplicates = dCits.GroupBy(x => x.Value).Any(g => g.Count() <=numero||(g.Count()==3||g.Count()==4));
```

Comment: se necesitan que sean menores o iguales a N numero dado o si son 3 o 4??